# mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, apache2.4, ubuntu-20.04, php-7.4

[image: the error messages]

I am doing an online course from coursera where they tolm me to install phpmyadmin.

NOW I am a total beginner in this thing so I am not able to do much research upon that and now somehow, after I installed MySQL and phpmyadmin, in the localhost, I am getting some errors, is that common? Because the other participants in the course are not getting them. If that's fatal or will limit some of my obvious abilities, please tell me how to cure it.

BTW If you didn't noticed the errors are:

`mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

and

`Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.`

Some more details:

1. PHP version is 7.4
2. Operating System is Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Try logging on a `root` without a password!! Or if your tutorial made you set a password for `root` then us that password

Comment: If you are a complete beginner, I would suggest you stick to a PHP7.4 as 7.5 is not actually relaeased yet and you may get odd issues that are the fault of pre-release code

Comment: I used the password that I created for root. It was a strong password with small, capital letters, numbers and special characters and easy to remember. And if I try logging without a password, I get a bunch of errors like  `Cannot log in to the MySQL server`   `mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`   `Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed`   `mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`. all at once :-(. what do you think I should do...

Comment: Sorry, its 7.4, my bad. I wrote it by mistake..

Comment: But you ar logging in with `phpMyAdmin` as the userid as denoted by the error message `Access denied for **user** 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost'`

Comment: IDK, I wrote `root` in the the username section.... not phpmyadmin

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 5):

I was using MaridDb solved this issue with the following:

```sh
sudo systemctl stop mariadb
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
mysql -u root
```

You will see a prompt like below:

Type `help;` or `\h` for help. Type `\c` to clear the current input statement.

```sql
MariaDB [(none)]> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

For MySQL 5.7.6 and newer as well as MariaDB 10.1.20 and newer

```sql
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';
```

OR:

For MySQL 5.7.5 and older as well as MariaDB 10.1.20

```sql
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('new_password');
```

Answer (score 5):

I've just installed LAMP on a new PC, and got the same problem.
Linux Mint 20 + MariaDB.
Password for root and phpmyadmin was already ok, but the error was still there.

Finally I discovered another configuration file, that sets the phpmyadmin password; you have to edit it:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf
```

set the correct password (= dbc_dbpass) for user `dbc_dbuser='phpmyadmin'`
Use ctrl-O to save, then ctrl-X to exit. Then launch the command:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

(Do NOT reinstall the DB).
In my PC il works!

Comment: doesn't solve on my ubuntu 20.04 (after _do-release-upgrade_ from 18.04, and mariadb 10.3.38 !

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with mysql 8.0.22 and Ubunutu 20.04.3lts after installation despite setting up the phpmyadmin user during the installation it wouldn't let me in with the password I set.

I solved it by logging in at the command line using

```
sudo mysql
```

Then changed the password by the below and I could then log in

```
ALTER USER 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new-password-here';
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem by changing the password of the root user and the problem was solved by changing the content of the config.inc.php file inside the xampp\phpMyAdmin folder.
Open the file with Notepad, then enter the defined password in front of the password field and that's it

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZWrW.png)
---[The part where the password must be entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAEwd.jpg)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).